# Comparing two timestam date

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I am working a monitor alert  functionality in our project .But i m facing issue related to show notification related to user like `"a minite ago"`,`"2 weeks ago"`,`"2 month ago"`, and `"1 year ago"` like this .
i use this method from google so i have no idea how to show this message like "2 weeks ago".I just compare the current date with stampdate ,
Stampdate means the alert created date.

Anyone have any suggestion to me.

```
 public static long compareTwoTimeStamps(java.sql.Timestamp currentTime, java.sql.Timestamp oldTime)
    {
        long milliseconds1 = oldTime.getTime();
      long milliseconds2 = currentTime.getTime();

      long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
      long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
      long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
      long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
      long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        return diffMinutes;
    }
```

Thanks

Sitansu

Comment: Consider having a look at [PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Android you could directly use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution)` from SDK.

```
String result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(1438927563, 1438927573, 0);
// prints: "10 seconds ago"
```

If not use [PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*10)));
//prints: “10 minutes from now”
```